# Delphi Out of resources

Tags: delphi, linker

Every project I compile with Delphi 7, in which I do ***not*** compile with run-time packages, gives a linker error: "Too many resources". Even a blank application gives this error.

In other words: Delphi died on me.

Comment: Remember: this happens even on a virgin new application!
I solved it (well, in a way) by re-installing Delphi. So it had nothing to do with my projects, it was purely a Delphi problem.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you try to build it from the command line?
(i.e., \Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\dcc32.exe)

Also, have you build any custom .RES files for this project?  If not, try deleting the default .RES that Delphi created for you, and let it get re-created by the project.

You can also force an update to the .RES file by changing something trivial, like the version #, saving your project, then changing it back again.

Sorry these are not answers... but hopefully we will find the issue with a little poking around.

Comment: It even happens on a new blank application!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't duplicate the resource inclusion, like having multiple {$R *.dfm} lines in a unit or multiple {$R *.res} for the project. Could also be included anywhere in a unit like {$R MyProject.res} as well...

Comment: It even happens on a new blank application!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a corrupted project.res file.  Try renaming the old and see if it is successfully recreated?

Comment: It even happens on a new blank application!

Answer (score 0):

I get this error in few projects in Delphi 6.

I found a workaround for this. PFB the details: (Take a backup of the .res file if it is  modified)

1. Change {$R .res} to {$R *.res}
2. Compile the project
3. Delete the .res file and place the original file (whose backup was taken)
4. Change the {$ *.res} to {$R .res}
5. Hit Compile/Build

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when you migrate a project from a previous version of Delphi.  The solution as mentioned earlier is to delete the **.res** file.